# Expected to return a value at the end of arrow function error

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have this error Expected to return a value at the end of arrow function consistent-return. Im not sure how I can prevent this.

Im trying to stop the Swiper carousel when the screen-size is below 1060px

```
    import Swiper from 'swiper';

    export default function () {
      let articlesGalleryCarousel;

      const doSomething = () => {
        const enableSwiper = () => {
          articlesGalleryCarousel = new Swiper('.js-swiper-container', {
            loop: true,
            slidesPerView: 'auto',
            centeredSlides: true,
            a11y: true,
            keyboardControl: true,
            grabCursor: true,
            pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
            paginationClickable: true,
            navigation: {
              nextEl: '.carousel-button--prev',
              prevEl: '.carousel-button--next',
            },
          });
        };

        const breakpoint = window.matchMedia('(max-width:1060px)');

        const breakpointChecker = () => {
          if (breakpoint.matches === true) {
            if (articlesGalleryCarousel !== undefined) articlesGalleryCarousel.destroy(true, true);
          } else if (breakpoint.matches === false) {
            return enableSwiper();
          }
        };

        breakpoint.addListener(breakpointChecker);

        breakpointChecker();
      };
      return doSomething;
    }
```

Comment: `26:34  error  Expected to return a value at the end of arrow function  consistent-return`

This is the error im getting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an [ESLint consistent-return](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/consistent-return) warning.

> "This rule requires return statements to either always or never
>   specify values"

Your function "breakpointChecker" did not returns something in case of the first IF statement.

Answer (score 1):

ESLint [is telling you](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/consistent-return) that an arrow function should always or never return a value.

You have one branch that returns a value (`return enableSwiper();`) and one that doesn't (if `breakpoint.matches` is true).

So -- do you want that function to always return a value or to never return a value?